# How to override CXF property 'maxChildElements' value in Jboss EAP?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf

I have JAX-WS web service endpoint integration in JBoss EAP 6.4.5 environment. Service returns XML, which has more than 50,000 child elements and I receive exception:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:857) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:101) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:896) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:894) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.17.redhat-1.jar:2.7.17.redhat-1]
        ... 263 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.push(InputElementStack.java:340) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2951) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2839) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1073) [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:196)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
        ... 269 more
```

How can I override property 'maxChildElements'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get raw Inputstream response from JAX-WS client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686564/how-can-i-get-raw-inputstream-response-from-jax-ws-client)

Comment: And check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416042/cxf-jaxws-issue-in-jboss-as-7-org-apache-cxf-staxutils-depthexceededstaxexcep

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in standalone-*.xml (* here is full, full-ha, etc.) right under <extensions> tag like:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:13.0">
    <extensions>
      ...
    </extensions>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements" value="100000"/>
</system-properties>
```

Tested on wildfly 20, maybe it would also work with your environment

Update [2020-09-23]

for some reasons I didn't really like this solutions, so in the end I had to exclude webservices subsystem in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.jws.api"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.ws.api"/>
            <module name="org.springframework.spring">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl">
                <imports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <include path="META-INF/cxf"/>
                    <include path="META-INF"/>
                </exports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and then my beans.xml file (in this case I named it as jbossws-cxf.xml)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd" default-lazy-init="false">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.class.package"/>
    <bean id="sampleEndPointImpl" class="my.class.package.MyserviceImplemenation"/>
    <jaxws:server id="POJOEndpoint"
    address="/lol"
    serviceName="s:myServiceNameInWsdlFileLol"
    endpointName="e:portTypeNameInMyWsdlFileLol"
    xmlns:e="http://www.My-endpoint-url.com/service"
    xmlns:s="http://www.My-endpoint-url.com/service">
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean class="my.class.package.MyserviceImplemenation"/>
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements" value="100000"/>
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:server>
</beans>
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/jbossws-cxf.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

NOTE:

My classes had to be annotated with spring annotation and CDI annotation, i.e

```
@Stateless <- cdi annotation
@Component <- spring annotation
public class MyRandomClass {

    public String test(){
        return new String("test");
    }

}
```

that I use in

```
@WebService(
        serviceName = "myServiceNameinWsdlLol",
        portName = "myportTypeNameInWSDLLol",
        targetNamespace = "http://www.my-tns-namespace.com/myService",
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl",
        endpointInterface = "com.my-tns-namespace.randompackage.myService"
) <- javax annotation
@Service <- spring annotation
public class MyServiceImplementation implements MyServiceEndpointInterface {

    @Inject <- javax annotation
    MyRandomClass myRandomClass;

    @Override
    public ResponseLol myServiceMethod(RequestLol request) {
        ResponseLol response = new ResponseLol();
        return responseLol;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I used words such as lol to indicate that the class or url is project
custom and not java framework specific.